# opencart product description on order email?

Tags: php

How can I display the product description in order email or admin order history in opencart? Since, I have only very short product description and I made the size as description instead. eg. 20x20kg. I have tried adding to controller `'description' => '$products['description']';`

and view on order. tpl, but it doesn't show anything.

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant content of your order.tpl file?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I added to model like this: 'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
or 
'description' => htmlspecialchars_decode($product['description']),          but unfortunately it doesn't work when I tried to echo it. please help .VIEW
catalog > view > theme > (mytheme) > template > mail > order.tpl
http://pastebin.com/zpcWyzsU

MODEL
catalog > model > checkout > order.php 
link: http://pastebin.com/37w7ix1Z